# Finding lowest & highest unit price for product based on latest date for a given amount and price (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So basically I have a table like the following:

```
        +----+-----------+---------+-------+-------+------------+
        | ID | ProductID | ShopID  | Amount| Price |  AddedDate |
        +----+-----------+---------+-------+-------+------------+
        | 1  | 1         | 1       | 1000  | 220   | 2020-07-01 |
        | 2  | 1         | 1       | 1000  | 230   | 2020-07-30 |
        | 3  | 1         | 1       | 100   | 21    | 2020-07-10 |
        | 4  | 1         | 1       | 100   | 22    | 2020-07-31 |
        | 5  | 1         | 2       | 100   | 23    | 2020-07-10 |
        | 6  | 1         | 2       | 100   | 20    | 2020-07-12 |
```

Just finding the lowest price for a product is pretty easy with
`lowestUnitPrice = product.Sales.Min(s => s.Price / s.Amount)`
same for the highest price `highestUnitPrice = product.Sales.Max(s => s.Price / s.Amount)`

However, as you can see, I'm keeping a price history. As such for determining the lowest latest unit price, I need to use only the latest entry for a given amount. In the table above, it should discard the row with ID 1 as the row with ID 2 has an identical amount, but a newer AddedDate.

I'm trying to find a solution with a single query, but I don't think it's possible. In SQL finding the lowest unit price would look something like this I think, given that table Sales here, are the sales for a specific product.

```
SELECT MIN(Price / Amount)
FROM productsales
WHERE (ProductID, AddedDate) IN 
 (SELECT ProductID, max(AddedDate) 
  FROM productsales 
  GROUP BY ProductID, ShopID, Amount
 )
```

The expected output from the above table would be 0.20 (row ID 6) for the lowest unit price, 0.23 (row ID 2) for the highest unit price.

SQL demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be74da/2

Comment: So you want it grouped by Shop id? If i give product Id 1, what record/s should it return. You need to be really specific

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I've added the sought output and also a SQL query that works.

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do it is

```cs
        var query = from p1 in products
                    where 
                       (from p2 in products
                        group p2 by new { p2.ShopID, p2.Amount } into g
                        select (g.Max(p2 => p2.AddedDate))
                       ).Contains(p1.AddedDate)
                    select (p1.Price / p1.Amount);
        decimal lowestPrice = query.Min();
        decimal highestPrice = query.Max();
```

Don't know if it can be done shorter or more efficiently?

Demo to be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRJzHs